# ngRepeat based on the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to change the number of elements to the number given by a select box.
My code:

**index.php**

```
<select class="form-control-static" ng-model="fieldSelect" ng-change="showSelectValue(fieldSelect)">
    <option ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>
```

**index.php**

```
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(1) track by $index")>
    Hello!
</div>
```

**default.js**

```
$scope.showSelectValue = function(fieldSelect) {
    contentFields = fieldSelect;
    $scope.getTimes();
};

$scope.getTimes=function(n){
    n = contentFields;
    return new Array(n);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this working example.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.getTimes=function(n){
   // Parse the value to int
   return new Array(parseInt(n));
};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
<select class="form-control-static" ng-model="fieldSelect" ng-init="fieldSelect=1">
    <option ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5] track by $index" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>
  
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(fieldSelect) track by $index")>
    Hello! {{$index}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html

```
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes({{fieldSelect}}) track by $index")>
   Hello!
</div>
```

In your function

```
$scope.getTimes=function(n){
   // Parse the value to int
   return new Array(parseInt(n));
};
```